# Magento2: How to get Reset password link in custom email template

Tags: magento2.3, customer-account, forgot-password

How to get Reset password link in the custom email template?
I am able to get a token like this -

```
$customToken = $this->_userHelper->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
$reset_password_link = $baseUrl.'customer/account/createpassword/?token='.$customToken;
```

but when click then getting a message like this "Reset password link has expired"

Comment: Did you got the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to access the link outside of your configured lifetime?

Stores -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Password Options -> Recovery Link Expiration Period (hours)

Increase this number

Comment: yes,i am using outside to access

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to fetch the correct token of the user

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry;
class Test
{
    const PATH_RESET_PASSWORD='customer/account/createPassword/?token=';
    public function __construct(
        CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storemgr
                   )
    {
        $this->customerRegistry = $customerRegistry;
        $this->_storeManager= $storemgr;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
                $Token=$this->customerRegistry->retrieveSecureData('CustomerId i.e 3')->getData('rp_token');
                echo "link::<br>".$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl().self::PATH_RESET_PASSWORD.$Token;

       }


    }
```

if this doesn't work then try to increase Recovery Link Expiration Period from configuration.

Comment: i tried this but not working